# Delete api call with body as payload in redux-saga

Tags: api, redux-saga

Request body sending no data with the following code, here I have used redux-saga to call make an API.

```js
yield call(api.delete, endpoint, { param },
      { headers: {Authorization: 'some token'}}, {body: { somekey: value}})
```

When I see in the browser request body is `{}`

Please let me know where I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are composing your request correctly. I am not sure what `param` is but try something like the below code.

```
yield call(api.delete, endpoint, {
     method: 'DELETE',
     url: endpoint,
     headers: {
        Authorization: 'some token',
     }, 
     body: { somekey: value, param: param}
})
```

There are a few ways you can do this but basically the headers, body, etc. need to be in the same object (in this case, the last argument passed to `yield call`). The way you have it they are effectively in two separate payloads.